# The short axle slides in and out of the gear easily by hand

Tags: manual-transmission, axle, ducato

Replaced my driver's side axle / driveshaft with a new one after I started getting vibrations while accelerating. Solved the vibration problem, but a few hundred kilometers later my gear box seized up. Replaced the gear box with one from a junkyard, drove about 150 kilometers and the next day while driving around my parking lot the shaft just popped out of the gear box. Parts shop swears it's the right driveshaft. With everything fully assembled I can easily pull the shaft cup out of the gear. That doesn't seem right, but I'm wondering if someone with more experience with Ducato gears and axles might be able to comment. I've been told that it's normal for Ducato's not to have retainer clips on their axles, so I'm wondering if this behavior is normal, because usually a bit of effort is need to pull an axle out of a gear.

[I uploaded a short video showing the problem here](https://youtu.be/u6aQfXsYQ_Y).

EDIT - The Gear side of the axle

[image]

Comment: Is this a new axle? On most vehicles I've dealt with, there is a snap ring which resides on the axle which should hold it in place when inserted correctly. I use the word "snap" ring, but I don't really know if that is what it is called. It should squeeze down and be allowed to go into the hole, the it would expand out when completely inserted, thus holding the axle in place. If this is a new axle, I'd see if it is there. Only thing I've got for you.

Comment: Can you upload a photo of what the end of that shaft looks like?  The part that goes into the gearbox?

Comment: Why does the inner CV joint rubber boot look so stretched?  Has the small diameter end just been fastened too far along the shaft?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 yeah, brand new axle. it didn't come with a snap ring and there wasn't one on the old axle.  People I've spoken with say the Ducato vans don't have snap rings on their axles.

Comment: @HandyHowie I uploaded the pic.  The boot looks a little stretched because it's not the original boot.  When the tow truck came to get the van after the gear seized up, he apparently managed to rip the original boot so they replaced it with what is apparently a smaller than standard boot.

Comment: If there's no snap ring on the axle, there has to be one inside the transmission. I'd suggest it would engage at the end of the spline (CV end of the splines). There has to be *something* there to hold the axle in place.

Comment: What does the other side drive shaft do when you pull on the CV joint?  Does it move?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I would think also, but from what I read, that usually is with differentials and you have to take them apart to get the axle out...

Comment: @HandyHowie If I pull in and out on the shaft perpendicular to the gear there's almost no movement, maybe one or two millimeters... No back and forth movement at all in the parallel plain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found out what the problem is:

[image: inner axle joint with spring]

The [inner axle joint](https://www.bestpartstore.co.uk/14928513-meyle-joint-kit-drive-shaft) is supposed to have a spring in it that keeps pressure on the cup to keep it in the transmission.

When my truck was loaded on the tow truck, they ripped the boot on the inner axle.  When the guys who replaced the transmission went to replace the boot before installing the axle, apparently the spring fell out without them noticing...

Here's what it's supposed to look like installed:

[image]

I would have thought this would have been the first thing to pop into the head of the guy who replaced the transmission, but... oh, well.